# Laravel Model::create - выполняется очень долго

Tags: laravel, request, eloquent

Вот простой пример кода, упростил его до минимума. Вот тут у меня и проседает скорость выполнения запроса
[image: create]

Время выполнения - Start - 0 End 21.631281137466
21 секунда... Но это не всегда, бывает запись создается и за пол секунды и скорее, но часто больше 6 секунд.
Валидации нет. Вот моя модель
[image: TestsMark]

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? На локальном сервере, все выполняется мгновенно. На боевом сервере - вот такие траблы.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы уверены, что в коде проблем нет (нет непонятных валидаций, или еще каких-либо связанных событий), то копайте в сторону БД :) Скорее всего ответ кроется в 4 ключевых моментах:

- "боевая" машина не такая уж и боевая: медленный hdd + слабые ресурсы самой виртуальной машины
- на ней висит (на таблице) слишком много ненужных индексов
- размер этой таблицы огромен
- если БД не локальна, по отношению к машине, на которой исполняется код, то возможно это сетевые задержки

Comment: Спасибо.  Может быть. Перезапустили MySql  - все начало летать, инсерты по 0,01 сек, но все-равно иногда проскакивают по 6-15 сек..., хотя реже(